# Unable to customize principal object, no matter how it always stays a string

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Initially the principal object in the authentication of spring security is a string, that simply contains the user id. By defining a custom user detail service or a custom authentication provider and extending the user object in spring security, the user information should be stored in the principal object. But no matter which of both i choose, the principal object always stays a string. For security we are using an authentication server with oauth2.

This is the version with a customized authentication provider. I already found a hint, that a field called forcePrincipleAsString might be the reason for my problem, although it should initially be set to false, and the customized authentication provider i use has no such field.

This is my custom authentication provider:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString().trim();
        SecurityUser appUser = new SecurityUser();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(appUser, password, new ArrayList<>());
  }
  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
      return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
  }

}
```

This is my web security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String REALM = "bam";

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider; 

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
            .logout()
            .and()
            //endpoints without authentication
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/logged", "/userData").permitAll()
            .and()
            // default with authentication
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}

    @Bean
    public OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor oAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(OAuth2ClientContext context, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(context, details);
    }
    // I added this code from an advice, but it didn't help
    @Bean
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint() {
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint basicAuth = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        basicAuth.setRealmName(REALM);
        return basicAuth;
    }
}
```

The extended user class looks like that:

```
public class SecurityUser extends User{

    String firstName;
    String name;
    String password;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SecurityUser() {
        super("user", "none", new ArrayList<>());
        firstName = "Rainer";
        name = "Schlund";
        password = "meins";
    }

    public String getRole(){
        return "Student";
    }


}
```

And at least after authentication at the code line with the `System.out.println` the customized services should have been called, but unfortunately they are not. Breakpoints in the customized services have never been reached and the principal is still a string and not my customized user:

```
@ComponentScan("edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/theses")
public class ThesisController {

    @Autowired
    private ThesisClient thesisClient;

    @Autowired
    private ThesisPersonLinker linker;

    @Autowired
    private ThesisPersonFilter filter;

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('theses')")
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<ThesisFrontendDTO>> findAllTheses() {
       System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
```

The code contains some simplifications for testing like SecurityPerson always returning the same person, but i think that should not be a problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Facing the same issue and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a `CustomAuthenticationProvider` only adds `Authentication` object to security context. In order to customize the `Principal` object you want in the security context, you will have to implement a [`UserDetailsService`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html).

[Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database) is a good primer.

Comment: I was told that both ways should work and i already implemented both and with custom userdetailsservice it is the same problem. It is also the same problem when both custom details service and custom authentication provider are active.